# i imported a map from sketchfab and i fall through it everytime and i dont know why unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

so i got a map from sketchfab (this the the map https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/volcano-island-lowpoly-4a6591dc9fee40d8bfda8350683af9af) i have researched this for like a couple hours now and i cant figure it out ive tried so many times but nothing works i tried adding a box collider to the map and the player but still i fall straight through im using a rigid body and a capsule and i have everything ticked off im pretty sure atleast and still cant figure it out someone please help i use unity3d

i was trying to make it so i can stay on the land and run up the volcano and go up the trees and all that kinda stuff but i fall through everything

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Mesh collider instead, and test with Convex option  checked/unchecked.

Note : You need to add the mesh collider to each part of the island you want to have collision
[image: how to]

Comment: nope it still didint work any other ideas

Comment: I updated my answer you can see that I added the mesh collider to each part of the island and it's working!